# Grails Unit Testing: Mocking ApplicationContext

Tags: unit-testing, grails, mocking

I have the following segment of code in a grails class:

```
 import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
 import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.ServletContextHolder
 import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsApplicationAttributes

    ApplicationContext ctx = (ApplicationContext)ServletContextHolder.servletContext.getAttribute(GrailsApplicationAttributes.APPLICATION_CONTEXT);

        def contentfulContentDeliveryService =   ctx.getBean('contentfulContentDeliveryService')
```

When I run unit tests, I get an error like:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getAttribute() on null object
```

How can I mock this?

Comment: What are you trying to test? A controller or something else (services, domain classes..)? I am asking because the servletContext is injected into controllers so that may be easier to mock..

Comment: These lines are present in a groovy source file in a grails project. This class is accessed from a service. I need to write test for this service.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way. I added the following lines to unit tests file.

```
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockServletContext
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsApplicationAttributes
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.ServletContextHolder

@TestFor(BannedWordsService)
class BannedWordsServiceTests {

    @Before
    void setUp(){

        def servletContext = new MockServletContext()
        servletContext.setAttribute(GrailsApplicationAttributes.APPLICATION_CONTEXT, mainContext)
        ServletContextHolder.setServletContext(servletContext) 
    -

    -

    } 


 }
```

Now when I run unit tests, I get an error as:

```
  org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'contentfulContentDeliveryService' is defined
```

How can I mock that line?

Comment: You forgot `def mainContext = new MockApplicationContext()`

Answer (score 0):

What about directly injecting `contentfulContentDeliveryService` into your class by registering it in `resources.groovy` and defining a bean reference as discussed in the [manual](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/spring.html)?

Something like:

```
myBean(MyClass) {
    contentfulContentDeliveryService = ref("contentfulContentDeliveryService")
}
```

Then you would have a simple property in your class and could mock it like any normal property.